# Positioning esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol at the center when clicked?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I use ArcGis Javascript api 3.2. I have a symbol:

```
candidateSymbol=new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('image/PushPin.png', 30, 30);
```

I want to center it when it is being clicked.

PS: There will be many such symbols on the map. I want to center the screen on the symbol that is being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following.

```
dojo.connect(map.graphics, "onClick", function(evt) {         
      var g=evt.graphic.geometry;
      map.centerAt(g);      
});
```

But it is important to make sure that this part of the code is placed after the "map" is instantiated. Failing to do so will through you a js error that "map object not found".

PS: candidateSymbol was part of the graphics layer.